# Filling the area between two lines on different scales/subplot axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to figure out how to fill between two lines that are on different scales & axes of subplot, however, I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

I have tried following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658845/how-to-fill-areas-between-curves-with-different-scales-in-a-plot) for a similar question, but the formula supplied in the code doesn't work on my dataset and based on the responses from the author of that question the equation doesn't appear to work when the x limits are changed.

The following image is what I am after (created in Photoshop):

[image: Shaded Plot]

However, using the code below, I get:

[image: Incorrectly Shaded Plot]

Example Data & Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({'DEPTH':[4300, 4310, 4320, 4330, 4340, 4350, 4360, 4370, 4380, 4390], 
                     'NEUT':[45, 40, 30, 12, 6, 12, 8, 10, 20, 18], 
                     'DENS':[2.5, 2.55, 2.32, 2.35, 2.3, 2.55, 2.58, 2.6, 2.52, 2.53]})

fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,20))

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax1.plot('DENS', 'DEPTH', data=data, color='red')
ax1.set_xlim(1.95, 2.95)
ax1.set_xlabel('Density')
ax1.xaxis.label.set_color("red")
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors="red")
ax1.spines["top"].set_edgecolor("red")

ax2.plot('NEUT', 'DEPTH', data=data, color='blue')
ax2.set_xlim(45, -15)
ax2.set_xlabel('Neutron')
ax2.xaxis.label.set_color("blue")
ax2.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.04))
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', colors="blue")
ax2.spines["top"].set_edgecolor("blue")

ax1.fill_betweenx(data['DEPTH'], data['DENS'], data['NEUT'], where=data['DENS']>=data['NEUT'], interpolate=True, color='green')
ax1.fill_betweenx(data['DEPTH'], data['DENS'], data['NEUT'], where=data['DENS']<=data['NEUT'], interpolate=True, color='yellow')

for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.set_ylim(4400, 4300)
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
    ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
```

Would anyone be able to help me with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your code and the answer you linked is that your Neutron scale goes from the maximum value on the left to the minimum value on the right, which means the logic is slightly wrong. So we just need to switch a few `min` and `max` terms around.

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({'DEPTH':[4300, 4310, 4320, 4330, 4340, 4350, 4360, 4370, 4380, 4390], 
                     'NEUT':[45, 40, 30, 12, 6, 12, 8, 10, 20, 18], 
                     'DENS':[2.5, 2.55, 2.32, 2.35, 2.3, 2.55, 2.58, 2.6, 2.52, 2.53]})

fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,8))

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax1.plot('DENS', 'DEPTH', data=data, color='red')
ax1.set_xlim(1.95, 2.95)
ax1.set_xlabel('Density')
ax1.xaxis.label.set_color("red")
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors="red")
ax1.spines["top"].set_edgecolor("red")

ax2.plot('NEUT', 'DEPTH', data=data, color='blue')
ax2.set_xlim(45, -15)
ax2.set_xlabel('Neutron')
ax2.xaxis.label.set_color("blue")
ax2.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.08))
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', colors="blue")
ax2.spines["top"].set_edgecolor("blue")

x = np.array(ax1.get_xlim())
z = np.array(ax2.get_xlim())

x1 = data['DENS']
x2 = data['NEUT']

nz=((x2-np.max(z))/(np.min(z)-np.max(z)))*(np.max(x)-np.min(x))+np.min(x)

ax1.fill_betweenx(data['DEPTH'], x1, nz, where=x1>=nz, interpolate=True, color='green')
ax1.fill_betweenx(data['DEPTH'], x1, nz, where=x1<=nz, interpolate=True, color='yellow')

for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.set_ylim(4400, 4300)
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
    ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")

plt.show()
```

(I changed the figure size so it would fit on my screen)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly with the full dataset I have.